# WATIR 5.0.0 is entering text value in textbox slower than WATIR 3.0.0

Tags: ruby, watir

I was using Ruby 1.8.7 and WATIR 3.0.0 and now I have changed to Ruby 2.0.0 and WATIR 5.0.0, the problem I have here is, It's entering the value in textbox very slowly compared to WATIR 3.0.0, What is the problem here? how would I resolve this problem? Can anyone suggest me? Or is it a problem in WATIR 5.0.0

Comment: Can you provide an example that easily reproduces the issue?

Comment: b.text_field(:id,'something').set("hi how are you") 

If you run the above line in Watir 3.0.0 and Watir 5.0.0, Watir 5.0.0 is extremely slow compared to Watir 3.0.0. What might be problem? Are you using Watir 5.0.0, Are you facing any problem like this?

Comment: I only use the watir-webdriver gem lately.  If you provide can additional data regarding your environment (e.g. browser, OS, etc.) and--even better--provide some benchmarking between the versions that illustrates the timing delta, it will help others help you.

Comment: Thanks, My OS is Windows 7 and Browser is IE 11.

 "provide some benchmarking between the versions that illustrates the timing delta"

I don't understand above line? between which versions?

Comment: Compare the text entry speed of ruby watir 3.0.0 versus watir 5.0.0.

Comment: hi, Can you please tell me how would I do this?